# Get true public IP of 4G router

Tags: networking, router, ip

I have a 4G router (TP-Link Archer MR200), that tells me in its GUI that it has a public IP of (just an example) `10.194.12.4`. If I do `curl ifconfig.me`, I get a different IP, like `90.153.17.52`. As far as I know, this has to do with CGNAT and how my SIM carrier handles SIM IP addresses. However, that IP I get from `ifconfig.me` (or any other "whats my ip" kind of service) is "wrong", and I can't access my router through it, while I can through the one my router tells me (I have set up port-forwarding and stuff like that).

I am currently trying to write a Python script to automatically update my No-IP dynamic ip correctly (since my router sends the wrong one), and I need to find a way to get that *true* public IP from the router, but I have found literally nothing regarding how to do that. I have searched for TP-Link APIs or linux utilities that allowed me to get that little bit of information about the router, to no avail, since everything on the internet is either for the public IP that I get from online services like `ifconfig.me` (the *wrong* public IP) or for the local IP.

I am planning on writing a web scraper for the router's control panel, but I'd like to know first if there is anything I can do to get the correct IP more easily.

Edit: I want to make a clarification: I have set up port forwarding to be able to SSH to my computer remotely. I can do `ssh user@10.194.12.4` without problems, exactly as I would do on a local network. I cannot do the same with the `90.x.x.x` IP. That's why I refer to the `10.x.x.x` IP as the true public IP and the `90.x.x.x` as the wrong one. My network is perfectly reachable through the `10.x.x.x` IP.

Edit 2: Nevermind, I've just figured out I have been accessing the network from networks under the same ISP, so I've been unknowingly accessing my computer over a really big LAN and not over the actual Internet >:P

Comment: Does your router support SNMP? Note that by including your router model my question would be abundant.

Comment: @mashuptwice It does indeed support it

Comment: Then check with a SNMP browser if your router exposes the WAN IP. Before you proceed, can you confirm that it is possible to SSH into your machine from a remote network, e.g. using a VPN or your phones hotspot? Note that if you are in the EU, your carrier is obligated to provide you a "true" public IPv4 address upon your request. It takes no more than an email, 1-2 days time and a APN change to set it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IP Address 10.x.x.x falls within the Internet's Private or Reserved
IP Address Space. There is no way that you can access it from the internet.
It's allocated by your ISP for your use, but has no validity outside
of the ISP's local network.

The IP address of `90.153.17.52` is probably the right IP address,
but you most likely share it with other users of your ISP, because that's
how CGNAT works. So it also can't be used to reach your computer from the
internet.

The only way you can make your computer reachable from the internet,
is to ask your ISP for a static IP address, which may require additional
payment. Once you get that static address, both the methods that you used
will result in the same IP address, and there won't be any "wrong" one.

Reference : Wikipedia
[Carrier-grade NAT (CGN or CGNAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

Comment: "The only way you can make your computer reachable from the internet, is to ask your ISP for a static IP address, which may require additional payment." There's also stuff like https://ngrok.com/.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Interesting.

Comment: Oh interesting. Does this mean if I use the IP Address I found from googling "what's my ip", and can get it to reach my router, it means my ISP is assigning a globally unique IP address to my router? I thought all ISPs always make IP addresses be shared among multiple users. (I could reach my router from that IP address, and successfully play Minecraft there with my friends)

Comment: @justhalf: This works more like a VPN, I think. It's also not free for serious stuff.

Comment: @justhalf As _originally designed_, not just every router, but every _computer_ on the Internet should have a unique IP address. However, it turns out that we quickly out-grew the 4 billion addresses available in IPv4, particularly because they weren't allocated very carefully early on, so _often_ ISPs reuse addresses for multiple users, which is the "CGNAT" referred to in the answer. It's certainly not _required_ for them to do so, though, so it's _possible_ you're lucky and have a unique address.

Comment: Small nitpick: a _static_ IP address is a slightly stronger requirement than a _dedicated_ address: when I was first online, in 1990s UK, it was common for dial-up ISPs to have a pool of addresses used on a "time-share" basis, so that you'd be allocated one each time you connected, but it would be directly routable back to you for the duration of that connection. A _static_ address was one that was allocated _even when you weren't using it_. Modern DSL and fibre lines generally have an always-connected home router; but such a scheme could still be used for mobile connections, for instance.

Comment: @IMSoP yea, that's my understanding too. So what happens when my IP address is shared with other users, when I try to access it from public?

Comment: @justhalf Remember that this site is not a forum - this comment section is for _improving this particular answer_, not having an extended discussion inspired by it. There's a Wikipedia link in the answer describing how Carrier-Grade NAT works, and plenty of other explanations online; if they leave you with a specific question, maybe you can ask it on a new page.

Comment: Right, sorry for that! Got it from the Wikipedia link. Basically it uses the ISPs port forwarding. I fully understand this now.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you haven't found anything regarding obtaining the "true" public IP address is simply because your router **does not have a public IP address at all.**

The 10.x.x.x address shown in its GUI is a *private* address (despite the GUI calling it "public"), but nevertheless it's the real address that the router was assigned by your ISP (SIM carrier).

What's shown by "what is my IP" services is not wrong either – it's the address used by your ISP's NAT gateway, which is exactly what those services are meant to report. (Your router being inside the ISP's global CGNAT is exactly like your computer having a private address and being inside the router's local NAT, and external services have no way to distinguish the two situations.)

So in other words, your ISP has not issued you *any* IPv4 address that you could use to access your 4G router externally. You would need to call them and see if they offer a dedicated public IP address as an extra service.

Comment: Then how am I able to access all of the services I expose on my network (using port forwarding and such) on the `10.x.x.x` IP?

Comment: @CiroGarcía: I assume you're accessing them either from within the network itself, or from another system connected to the exact **same** ISP, which is therefore in the same 10.x.x.x network as your 4G router. ("Private address" does not mean "LAN address"; if the ISP wants to use private addresses across the entire country it can perfectly well do so. So in the case of CGNAT it's normal that one customer's device could still connect to another.)

Answer (score 0):

Others have discussed the nature of your problem. Here is one solution to circumvent the fact that you don't really have an IP per se: if IPv6 is an option, you may retain the services of an IPv6 broker, of which there are many. As an example. Hurricane Electric offers a free IPv6 broker. On the surface, it works like a VPN, but instead a huge IPv6 address block is assigned to you. Under the hood, various optimizations are performed. Since a lot of brokers are big players located in many datacenters, they can route your traffic efficiently without requiring your packets to go far.

https://ipv6.he.net

Comment: Hurricane Electric might not be a very good choice here, as having a public IPv4 address is kind of a _prerequisite_ for HE, and IP-in-IP tunnels aren't very reliable when the endpoint is behind a NAT. For mobile 4G users, some kind of UDP-based tunnel (e.g. WireGuard) would be a better option.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware, thanks.