# My Router Interface and whatismyipaddress.com shows different IP addresses

Tags: router, ip

My Router's Interface and whatismyipaddress.com show two different IP addresses.

My router interface under DNS connection, IP address is 100.73.177.xxx
And whatismyipaddress.com gives 180.150.80.xxx

When I started a apache server with a ubuntu test web page, 100.73.177.xxx works. Otherwise I cannot connect the web page.

And 100.73.177.xxx IP address has been there for a long time. I haven't asked for a static IP address from my provider.

Why is the reason for this? I haven't seen an IP address starting with 100 before.

P.S. This question is unique to this forum because, a similar answer states that "there is no way to reach this IP from outside of my service provider's local network" However, in my case, I can use it for web hosting and reach it from another device with another ISP. How can this be possible? No answer in this forum answers this question.

Comment: find and download `mtr` (My TraceRoute) - run it  as `mtr -i 15 www.google.com`  (from cmd.com / termina l /bash ) - as it brings up the "gui", hit `n` a few times so that you see IP-numbers... then look for those IP:s you have found out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get true public IP of 4G router](https://superuser.com/questions/1736877/get-true-public-ip-of-4g-router)

Comment: As you said, there is no way to reach it outside from my ISP's local network. But I can. I can reach it from another device from another ISP. I haven't paid for a static IP.

Comment: Then this will depend on the specifics of the service offered by your ISP, most likely. Have you communicated with your provider regarding this yet? Also, please add details to your question. The information you've revealed in your comment is not in the question and it needs to be there, along with any other pertinent information.

Comment: I am seeing exactly the same thing -- and it started at what I assume is a similar time. What ISP are you using? (I am CF in the UK.)

Answer (score 0):

`100.73.177.xxx` belongs to IP range `100.64.0.0/10` which is reserved for [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

Your private IP address is temporarily translated to a publicly accessible IP address.

Comment: Temporarily, but It has been a long time. Who does this, my service provider? And why?

Comment: Since I can use it for web hosting, it seems it belongs to me only. What is the benefit for my service provide  to do this. I still have an IP for myself. This does not make sense.

Comment: @lid: You missed the part where 100.64.0.0/10 is a *private* address range, in the same vein as 192.168.0.0/16. The benefit, therefore, is the same as using private addresses in your LAN: the ISP can share a public IP address between devices; i.e. it can have more customers than it has public IP addresses.

Comment: @u1686_grawity It is a private address and this is the confusing part. Because I can host a web page and reach this web page using this 100.73.177.xxx IP from another device using a different ISP for its connection.

Comment: @lid: Are you sure it's indeed a different ISP and not just a reseller? It's possible for ISPs to route private addresses by mutual agreement, but it's more likely you're actually on the same network...

Comment: @u1686_grawity Good point. Thank you. I will test it with a connection from another country. I will update here.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I wanted my brother connect using this IP from another country and he could not connect. If you write what you have said in your last comment as an answer, I accept it. Some other people may need this information. It is confusing.